# C++ private class dynamic n-dimensional array

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation, n-dimensional

I've been looking all around StackOverlow for an answer but i didn't find one so i hope it isn't duplication of any post around here.

so, i have the next problem.
lets say i have the next 2 classes: **Rectangle** (Which is built from another class but it doesn't concern us currently)
and **Grid**.
with they following constructors:

(Point Constructor for Rectangle private topLeft and bottomRight):

```
Point::Point(int x, int y) {this->x = x; this->y = y;}
```

(Rectangle Constructor and Class)

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
        Rectangle(int l, int u, int w, int h, int color);
        //int getColor() const;
        //void setColor(int color);
        //bool contains(const Point &p) const;
        //void print() const;
private:
        const Point topLeft, bottomRight;
        int color;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(int l, int u, int w, int h, int color) :
topLeft(l, u),
bottomRight(l + w, u + h)
{ this->color = color; }
```

(Grid Constructor and Class) (Lets assume I don't want to initialize the values of Rectangle in Grid just allocate them in memory)

```
class Grid
{
public:
    Grid(int tileW, int tileH, int width, int height, int color);
    //~Grid();
    //Rectangle& getRectAt(const Point &p);
    //void print() const;
private:
    int count;  
    Rectangle **recs;
};

Grid::Grid(int tileW, int tileH, int width, int height, int color)
{
    int index, index_c=0;
    recs = new Rectangle *[width];

    for (int index = 0; index < width; index++)
    {
        recs[index] = new Rectangle[index];
    }

}
```

so, as you can understand i have problem in Grid constructor with the following Error
(Error  1   error C2512: 'Rectangle' : no appropriate default constructor available.)
but i just cant understand why it wont work, I've been suggested to allocate the Recs double pointer as 1 dimensional array (Array with the length of Width*Height) but what if Recs was 4 dimensional array ? How could you flat it properly and then index around the 4-dimensional array without having a headache calculating the index of each cell in the array.

another thing, we know that if it was int** and not recs** it would work perfectly

```
int **foo;
int height,width;
foo = new int* (height);
for (int index = 0; index<height; ++index)
    foo[index] = new int[width];
```

so i just keep missing the way of doing n-dimensional arrays in C++.

Comment: Regarding your error: you have no default constructor in `Rectangle` nor any that takes an integer as parameter. Plus I kinda suggest using `std::vector`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `recs[index] = new Rectangle[index];` tries to call Rectangle's default constructor `index` times. If you want to create multiple objects at once, you probably want to add default ctor and simple setter method to your Rectangle class

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(int l, int u, int w, int h, int color);
    Rectangle() = default;
    void set(int l, int u, int w, int h, int color);
private:
    const Point topLeft, bottomRight;
    int color;
};
```

Then, in creation loop:

```
for (int index_w = 0; index_w < width; index_w++)
{
    recs[index_w] = new Rectangle[height]; //see note below
    for (int index_h = 0; index_h < height; index_h++)
        recs[index_w][index_h].set(/* some math with width, height and loop variables*/, color);
}
```

**Note**: I have changed `index` to `height`, because you want to create 2D array, so the total grid size is height * width. With index length in creation, you would create triangle-shaped grid instead (and more over, the first loop iteration would be `recs[0] = new Rectangle[0]` -  a zero-length array).

As user Macro A mentioned, consider using `std::vector<Rectangle>` instead of raw pointers (2D array would be `std::vector<std::vector<Rectangle>>`)

Also, consider changing your design, because currently you are creating a grid H x W of Rectangle objects, where all points (except first/last) are duplicated across adjacent rectangles (each point is upper-left corner of one rectangle, upper-right corner of another, bottom-left...).

I propose a Grid class that holds 2D array of ints and has a method `Rectangle getRectangle(int x, int y)` which would return appropriate set of 2 points. Modyfying such Grid class would be much easier, and you wouldn't have to iterate over all Rectangles, just ints

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *placement new* : you initially reserve enough place to store the array of objects, then individually construct them each in its own place.

In your code, it could become (more or less):

```
for (int index = 0; index < width; index++)
{
    // first simple allocation for the array
    recs[index] = (Rectangle *) malloc(sizeof(Rectangle) * height);
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        // individually build each rectangle in place
        new(&recs[index][j]) Rectangle(index*tileW, j*tileH, tileW, tileH, color); 
    }
}
```

This is intended to do exactly what you need : build arrays of non default constructible objects.

Unrelated: as you use raw pointers and allocated arrays, do not forget to correctly free everything. Using `std::vector`s could save you from that...

Answer (score 0):

You get error C2512 because you don't have a default constructor in `Rectangle`. The only constructor you have in `Rectangle` is parameterized, while a default constructor has the requirement that it must be callable without additional arguments provided.

Looking at the line `recs[index] = new Rectangle[index];`, you see there are no arguments for the 5 parameters the constructor accepts. For that line to compile, you need to create a default constructor either with a new constructor with the signature `Rectangle()` or default arguments for the parameters in your parameterized constructor, for example `Rectangle(int l = 0, int u = 0, int w = 0, int h = 0, int color = 0);`.

If you want to allocate the memory, you should create the default constructor and use `std::vector<Rectangle>` which you initialize with a size. Then you can later replace the objects by use of a copy-constructor, as shown in this example: http://ideone.com/KnUBPQ

As for creating an n-dimensional array, you've explicitly limited it to a two-dimensional array with your `Rectangle` and `Point` classes. If the array is going to be n-dimensional, your points need to be n-dimensional too:

```
template<int dimensions>
class Point
{
    std::array<int, dimensions> coords;

    ...
};
```

or

```
class Point
{
    std::vector<int> coords;

    ...
};
```